# How to make integers comparable

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I am trying to use the comparable interface to sort a randomly generated array, but I'm getting the error message:

incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to Comparable[]

```
int [] list;
list = new int[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    list[i]=(int)(1+n*Math.random());
}
sortingoutsorts.bubble(list);
}
private static void swap(Object [] list, int x, int y)
{
    Object temp=list[x];
    list[x]=list[y];
    list[y]=temp;
}
public static void bubble(Comparable [] list)
{
    boolean done=false;
    while(!done)
    {
        done=true;
        for(int i=0; i+1<list.length; i++)
            if(list[i].compareTo(list[i+1])>0)
            { swap(list,i,i+1); done=false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

Comment: Or use `<` and `>` to compare ints.

Answer (score 6):

int is a primitive data type and you can't implement Comparable on a primitive data type. You want to use its Wrapper class instead, [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), which already implements Comparable.

However, if you don't want to change your variable's type, you could probably change

```
if(list[i].compareTo(list[i+1])>0)
```

to

```
if(list[i] > list[i+1])
```

and change bubble signature to accept any array of int.

Comment: Yeah, there is a *reason* why [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has 8 overloads of the [`sort(array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#i112) method.

Comment: It is still a good exercice to implement sort by himself, even though bubble is not really great haha.

Comment: Sure, he just shouldn't expect a single method to sort both object arrays and *primitive* arrays.